# How to append text in the beginning of each line using sed

Tags: command-line, scripts, sed, text, dash-shell

```
<AppendNhere> A  H  W  C  
<AppendNhere> A  H  W  C
<AppendNhere> A  H  W  C
```

`Sed '/^/ i N' filename`

I tried appending `N` using this, but it's appending `N` to the beginning of new lines and not at the start of existing rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with

```
sed -e "s/^\(.*\)/N \1/" filename
```

This inserts the string `N` at the beginning of the line (`^`).

Comment: There's no such string that we can replace it with. All i need is to add N to beginning of existing lines.

Comment: Ok. I changed the answer to copy all characters to the position after `N`. This solution does work, but the other one above is better...

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to understand "quoting" (see `man bash`) and regular expressions (`man 7 regex`) and use `sed`'s (`man sed` "substitute" command.

```
sed -e 's/^/N/' filename
```